# Is there any efficient way to optimize following Linq

Tags: c#, performance, linq

```
private static List<Patient> GetPatientData()
{
    return  new List<Patient>()
    {
        new Patient(1,new List<Case>() { new Case(10, CaseType.ambulant)}),
        new Patient(2,new List<Case>() { new Case(20, CaseType.ambulant), new Case(21, CaseType.ambulant), new Case(22, CaseType.stationaer),new Case(23, CaseType.teilstat) }),
        new Patient(3,new List<Case>() { new Case(30, CaseType.ambulant), new Case(31, CaseType.ambulant), new Case(32, CaseType.stationaer), new Case(33, CaseType.stationaer), new Case(34, CaseType.teilstat) }),
        new Patient(4,new List<Case>() { new Case(40, CaseType.ambulant), new Case(41, CaseType.stationaer), new Case(43, CaseType.teilstat), new Case(44, CaseType.ambulant), new Case(45, CaseType.stationaer), new Case(46, CaseType.teilstat) }),
        new Patient(5,new List<Case>() {new Case(53, CaseType.teilstat),new Case(54, CaseType.teilstat) })
    };                                 
}

List<Patient> patientList = GetPatientData();
var result = patientList.SelectMany(item => item.CaseList.Select(itemCase=> itemCase.CaseType).Distinct());            
foreach (CaseType item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("CaseTypes = {0}",item);                
}
```

The above code gives the list of Patient, from that I want a distinct case list. So is there any optimized way to do this from what I have done?

```
    Dictionary<int, int> result = patientList.ToDictionary(item => item.PatientID , item=> item.CaseList.Select(x=>x.CaseType).Distinct().Count());            
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int,int> item in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", item.Key,item.Value);
    }
```

In Second case i am trying to get patientID & Distinct CaseType Count for that particular patient. can i optimize this one.

Comment: No, that looks fine to me. Do you have an actual performance *issue* with it?

Comment: Why do you think this code needs optimization? Does it run slowly? Have you used a profiling-tool to varify this?

Comment: Is the first number a unique ID number?  You can group by ID and then take the FirstOrDefault from the each group.  Patients.GroupBy(x => x.ID).Select(y => y.FirstOrDefault).ToList();

Comment: Thanks for your comments.                                                                          I was trying to make it efficient way.no issue with this code.and not tried with profiling-tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the distinct case types of all patients in that list, I used

```
var result =
    (
    from patient in patientList
    from typ in patient.CaseList
    select typ.CaseType
    ).Distinct();

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("CaseTypes = {0}", item);
}
```

Of course, you could rewrite it method-style.

To get the same distinct case list, but *per patient*, try this:

```
var result =
    (
    from patient in patientList
    group patient by patient.PatientID into g
    from patient in g
    from typ in patient.CaseList
    select new { ID = g.Key, Type = typ.CaseType }
    ).Distinct();

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Patient {0} has the following case: {1}", item.ID, item.Type);
}
```

An alternative (less repeating) way to present the results is to group:

```
var result =
    (
        from patient in patientList
        group patient by patient.PatientID into g
        from p in g
        select new { g.Key, List = p.CaseList.Select(c => c.CaseType).Distinct() }
    ).ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.List);

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Patient {0} has the following cases:", item.Key);
    foreach (var type in item.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", type);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a last Distinct:

```
var result = patientList.SelectMany(item => item.CaseList.Select(itemCase => itemCase.CaseType).Distinct()).Distinct();
```

There's nothing to improve there.

You could choose to keep only the last Distinct (so there's one less Enumerator to be created) but having it gives you less results yielded out to your final Distinct. Performance then would change depending on the amount of data (number of Patients and Cases per Patient) though nothing that would make any difference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1977143/bruno-garcia thanks for comment, but watever you suggesting is doing more filtering on my data which i dont want to do.

Comment: Seems from your question you wanted a distinct list of cases across all patients. The way you enumerate on your example you'll multiple results for the same case without the context of the patient. Didn't make much sense to me.